# ¿Como hago que el arreglo se imprima con sus respectivos datos?

Tags: java, array, constructor

Este programa lee el nombre de los alumnos y su sexo, luego genera una calificacion aleatoria, pero tengo el siguiente problema:

debo de generar calificaciones aleatorias, para poder imprimiras en el programa, usando la clase Alumno, pero al usar el metodo toString() solo me imprime la ultima calificacion del ultimo alumno para cada alumno.

Coloque un System.out.println() que imprime los numeros aleatorios generados que se añaden al arreglo calificaciones, que proximamente se añade al arreglo de tipo alumnos, y como se ve en la imagen los numeros salen aleatoreamente de forma correcta.

¿Me estoy olvidando de algo?

[image: Resultado del programa, primera parte]

[image: Resultado del programa, segunda parte]

MAIN:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Random; //importe de libreria random
//Clase grupo
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //30 alumnos y 7 materias
        int cantidadAlumnos = 3;
        String materia[] = {"matematicas","español", "arte", "fisica", "quimica", "literatura", "ingles"};
        //arreglo tipo persona
        Alumno alumnos[] = new Alumno[cantidadAlumnos];

        String nombre;
        char sexo;
        int calificaciones[] = new int[7];
        Random aleatorio = new Random(); //Creacion de random

        //ingreso de datos del alumno
        for (int i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Escribe el nombre del alumno " + (i+1));
            nombre = Key.readString();
            System.out.println("Escribe el sexo de " + nombre);
            sexo = Key.readChar();

            //ingreso de calificaciones (aleatorio)
            for (int j = 0; j < calificaciones.length; j++) {
                calificaciones[j] = 5 + aleatorio.nextInt(6);
                System.out.println(calificaciones[j]);
            }
            alumnos[i] = new Alumno(nombre,sexo,calificaciones); //creacion de alumno
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++) { //imprimir los alumnos en string
            System.out.println("Alumno " + (i+1));
            System.out.println(alumnos[i].toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Clase Alumno:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Alumno {
    //Atributos
    String nombre;
    char sexo;
    int[] calificaciones;

    //constructor de objeto
    public Alumno(String nombre, char sexo, int[] calificaciones) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.calificaciones = calificaciones;
    }
    public double calculoCalificacion(){

        return 0;
    }

    //imprimir a String el alumno
    public String toString() {
        return "Alumno{" +
                "nombre: " + nombre  +
                ", sexo: " + sexo +
                ", calificaciones: " + Arrays.toString(calificaciones) +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En java todo son referencias cuando pasas parámetros a funciones o cuando haces asignaciones. Así que en tu clase `Alumno`, estás guardando la referencia al array de calificaciones que creas y rellenas en la función donde vas creando los alumnos. Así que todos tienen una referencia al mismo objeto.

Para el primer alumno rellenas el array de calificaciones y se lo pasas al constructor. Este guarda la referencia a ese array.
Para el siguiente alumno vuelves a rellenar el array, y todas las referencias que apuntan a ese mismo objeto se verán afectadas. Así, el último relleno es el único que vale.

Solución:

Copiar el array que recibes en el constructor de la clase Alumno para que los objetos sean diferentes y cada Alumno tenga sus propias calificaciones.

Para copiar un array en otro, puedes usar la función `arraycopy` de la clase `System`:

```
System.arraycopy(array_org, 0, array_destino, 0, array_org.length);
```

O puedes hacer un bucle recorriendo cada elemento del array original e ir copiándolos en el array de destino.